# control internet speed windows server 2012 r2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, local-area-network

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2, and i have 30 client.
my LAN topology like this :

**Router** (IP: 192.168.1.1/255.255.255.0, DHCP: 192.168.1.2-254) => **Switch**
 (d-link dgs 1012) => **windows server 12r2** (IP:192.168.1.2, GW:192.168.1.1, DNS: 192.168.1.2) => **clients** (IP: 192.168.1.3-32).

i need to limit the internet speed to all clients:

- example : download / upload
- Administrator : Unlimited/Unlimited
- User1    : 50mbps download ,10mbps upload.
- User2 : 10mbps download  ,2mbps    upload.

is there any possible options or configuration in windows server 12r2 can do this ?
i have read about NIC Teaming and i still confused about it "i have 2 LAN Cards on my Server".

can anyone suggest me a good configuration of IP's in the LAN?

Comment: Do all your clients really route all their traffic through the server? That would be a very unusual network setup. More common would be that the server is, from a networking perspective, a peer to the clients on the same subnet.

Comment: i am going to setup my Network like that , i need all clients get the internet from the server to control the speed of internet and the traffic.

Comment: what do you think , how should i setup the LAN to avoid any problem in my Network ?

Comment: I think @MichaelKjörling was saying that having your _server_ as a network gateway between your clients and the internet would be unusual, and may not do what you are hoping it will. More common is to have a gateway device (a router, appliance, or system running something like a proxy and firewall) to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, can not do. That needs an enterprise grade firewall - one where the userhas to run a client to authenticate him on the firewall so that the firewall can then figure out his limites based on some policy.

Not only can Windows not do it, most firewalls can not - they purely work on the basis of some sort of IP based scheme. But IP's are at best computers (and can move/change) not user rights.

The old TMG (Thread Management Gateway) could do it - product was retired 2010.

Btw., the setup is odd to start with - you should NOT abuse a server as a router.

The best you can do these days is along the line of putting in a MIkrotik switch and use the acceess contorl mechanism made for wifi hotspots to force users to log in and hen assign them a profile based on group memberships. This login part if critical - as a login is the ONYL way to RELIABLY know what policy to apply to a user.

Comment: so you means i should see if i can configure the switch would be better and avoid routing from server ..

Comment: Nope. "Configure the switch" should simply not be necessary to start with. Switches do not need configuration for basic work. In fact, I would argue your diagram is faulty likely.

Comment: i don't think so .. the LAN diagram is too simple i install them one by one from the router to the clients PC's ..
now i am going to start the server setup / configurations .

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented pfsence in place of Router to control the upload and download speeds for either a particular IP or range of IP addresses. pfsence has many useful features to control the network activities. Here you can set proxy, block sites and do WAN failover/load balancing.
Still your Windows Server can serve DNS for LAN. Use Windows Server IP address as secondary DNS in DHCP for internal name resolution.

Answer (score -1):

You could look into deploying something like Netlimiter with remote access to client PCs.

Comment: Can you please add more detail to your answer? As written, it's more of a "the answer is over there" clue than a standalone answer.